# How can I use the template parameter of a class as the template parameter of a class member?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement the following in C++:

```
template <class T>
class Inner
{
public:
    Inner(T inData){data = inData;};
    ~Inner(void){};

    T data;
};

template <class T>
class Outer
{
public:
    Outer(Inner<T> in){inner = in;};
    ~Outer(void){};

    Inner<T> inner;
};

int main(void)
{
    Inner<int> in (10);
    Outer<int> out (in);

    std::cout << out.inner.data;
}
```

Compiled in MSVS 2010, I get the following error:

```
c:\...\main.cpp(15): error C2512: 'Inner<T>' : no appropriate default constructor available
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          c:\users\gaff\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pgp(c++)\pgp(c++)\main.cpp(15) : while compiling class template member function 'Outer<T>::Outer(Inner<T>)'
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          c:\users\gaff\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pgp(c++)\pgp(c++)\main.cpp(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Outer<T>' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
```

Clearly I'm missing some basic understanding here but I have no clue how to fix this, or even if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

For what it's worth, here is a Java implementation that compiles without any problems:

```
public class Inner<T> {
    public T data;

    public Inner(T inData) {
        data = inData;
    }
}

public class Outer<T> {

    public Inner<T> inner;

    public Outer(Inner<T> in) {
        inner = in;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Inner<Integer> in = new Inner<Integer>(10);
        Outer<Integer> out = new Outer<Integer>(in);

        System.out.println(out.inner.data);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers

JimmidyJoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a default constructor for inner. When the compiler initializes the object it calls the default constructor of `inner` before the assignment.

EDIT:

It's probably a good idea to properly implement a copy constructor and instead initialize inner like so:

```
Outer(Inner<T> in) : inner(in) { };
```

You could use the copy constructor like so:

```
Inner(const Inner<T> & in) : data(in.data){
}
```

Comment: That's not a copy constructor.  A copy constructor is `Outer(Outer const&)`

Comment: @Neil G: I never said it was a copy constructor, I said implement one and then initialize inner using it.

Comment: @GWW, Ah, you mean for Inner.  But, what would you put in such a copy constructor?  The default copy constructor for Inner should be fine.  T already has to be copy-constructible since the constructor takes a T by value.

Comment: @Neil G: I suppose that is true that the default one will probably be fine.

Comment: Thanks GWW.  Answer noted along with comments.

Comment: @GWW: Well, why not initialize `data` aswell in an initializer list?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an initializer list in the constructor:

```
Outer(Inner<T> in): inner(in) {}
```

otherwise the constructor has to default construct inner before it gets into the constructor.  That's impossible since there is no default constructor.

Comment: @littleadv: The default copy constructor is fine because T is guaranteed to be copy-constructible since it's being passed by value.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  GWW's response nominated as accepted answer since he submitted ahead of you by all of 3 minutes.  I note your comments on his answer.